# How do declare variables with a loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, variable-declaration

Is there a way to declare a series of variables like shown using a loop?

```
int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10;
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    cout << "Enter number " << i << ": ";
    cin >> n(i);
}
```

Comment: `int n[10]; for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { cin >> n[i]; }` perhaps?

Comment: Not possible, but also not necessary when you have arrays.